# How to filter by year for some period columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to pull a report of the previous year's usage based on Year and Period(month)
I adjusted the top line to add a filter for AND demand_period.year_for_period = YEAR(getdate()) but then realized that it will also remove the possibility of last year's results.
Prior to adding the YEAR statement, it was providing full sums of the usage for all years, broken down by month.
Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT (inv_mast.item_id) as [Item ID]
    ,inv_mast.item_desc as [Item Description]
    ,address.name as [Prim Supplier Name]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN (demand_period.period = MONTH(getdate()) AND demand_period.year_for_period = YEAR(getdate()))THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period1Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '2' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period2Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '3' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period3Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '4' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period4Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '5' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period5Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '6' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period6Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '7' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period7Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '8' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period8Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '9' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period9Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '10' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period10Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '11' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period11Usage]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN demand_period.period = '12' THEN inv_period_usage ELSE 0 END) AS [Period12Usage]
FROM inv_mast
    JOIN inv_loc ON inv_loc.inv_mast_uid = inv_mast.inv_mast_uid
    JOIN inventory_supplier_x_loc ON inventory_supplier_x_loc.location_id = inv_loc.location_id
    JOIN inventory_supplier ON inventory_supplier.inventory_supplier_uid = inventory_supplier_x_loc.inventory_supplier_uid
    JOIN supplier ON supplier.supplier_id = inventory_supplier.supplier_id
    JOIN address ON (address.id = supplier.supplier_id)
    JOIN inv_period_usage ON inv_period_usage.location_id = inv_loc.location_id
    JOIN demand_period ON (inv_period_usage.demand_period_uid = demand_period.demand_period_uid)
WHERE
    (inv_loc.location_id = '100001')
    AND (inventory_supplier_x_loc.primary_supplier = 'Y')
    AND (inv_mast.item_id = '111')
GROUP BY item_id, item_desc, name
```

How could I edit the SELECT statements to include the last 12 months, including if they are in a previous year?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
and demand_period.year_for_period >= DATEADD(month, -12, getdate())
```